# Changing user password logged in as Admin

Tags: windows, windows-xp, passwords, login, domain

I forgot my Windows XP password to logon to my laptop. My username is on the "Office" domain for work.  When I logon as the Administrator I have to logon to the local domain "This computer".

How do I reset my password for my account on the other domain?

Answer (score 5):

Are you an Administrator of that domain at work? If not, your best bet would be to contact the IT department and get them to reset it for you. If it was that easy to reset a user's password on a remote domain, that would be a huge security flaw. You need to have some sort of access to the domain controller itself through an Administrative account.

Comment: Is the password not stored locally somewhere where I can reset it?

Comment: No, your credentials are stored on the company's server.

Comment: But I haven't logged onto this laptop in a couple months so it has an old password.  When I logon with the old password and connect to the internet for work then it asks me to ctrl+alt+del to check my credentials.  Then I supply it with my current password.  

So where is that old password being stored?

Comment: Windows always caches the domain password on the machine for cases where the user wants to login without the domain being available.
However it does not allow a user the change it. It is just kept for temporary authentication purpose.

Comment: As well, it's stored securely so people can't read it from say, the registry